# ggsave() options for grid arrangements in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

`ggsave()` doesn't seem to work with the grid package (see below). How do I save this combination of plot `p1` and plot `p2`. The following code only save the last plot `p2` that ggplot() sees.

```
library(tidyverse)
p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(fl)) + geom_bar()
p2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_col()
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), size = "last"))
ggsave("mpg.png")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `gridExtra`. As explained in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html), `gridExtra`, building off of `gtable` (a higher-level layout scheme), provides more facility in arranging multiple grobs on a page, while `grid` package provides low-level functions to create graphical objects (grobs).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(fl)) + geom_bar()
p2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_col()

p <- grid.arrange(p1, p2)

ggsave(plot=p, filename="myPlot.png")
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: utilizing the `size = "last"` argument of `rbind()` I was able to keep the size of the original two plots identical. Is the same possible utilizing your method? It's hard to tell in this ReprEx, but there is a difference, and in my actual plot it's quite noticeable. Thank you.

Comment: I posted the very image that is outputted. They share same width. Not sure what else you need.

Comment: If I use this method from your comment somehow my saved image is cropped (mine is very wide as two horizontally next to each other) on the right side (maybe by a cm or two). Do you  have any clue why this could be?

Comment: @canIchangethis, possibly this is data-related. Please ask a new question with specific code implementation and data for [mcve].

Comment: weird, because I had it with 2 graphs. Thanks, I will do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the new combination first then use ggsave() to print it.

```
# here I name it to_print    
  to_print <- rbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), size = "last")


ggsave(filename = "mpg.png", plot = to_print)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I tried it and the file created "mpg.png" is only 1.74KB in size. And it's all white, no plots are on the image. Resolution is 1606x1071 so ggsave() is doing something.

Comment: I agree with the answer below by Parfait. Try using grid.arrange. You can also specify the resolution and quality of ggsave. 

For example: to_print <- grid.arrange(p1, p2)

ggsave(filename = "mpg.png", plot = to_print, width = 4, height = 4, unit = "in")

`ggsave(filename = "mpg.png", plot = to_print, width = 10, length = 10, unit = "inches")

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this.

```
#plotFile
g1=file.path(HomeDir,plotFile)
f1=grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol=2, top=textGrob("Multiple Plots", gp=gpar(fontsize=12, font = 2))) #arranges plots within grid
g <- arrangeGrob(f1) #generates g
#save
ggsave(g1, g,width = 29.7, height = 21, units = 'cm') #saves g
```